# How to change resolution to 2560x1080?

Tags: hdmi, display-resolution

Just installed ubuntu and I'm using it with an ultrawide monitor, with HDMI but I can't set the resolution to that on the settings menu. What's another way to do it?

Comment: Have you installed graphic driver?

Comment: It installed it on its own

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it, all I had to do was update the AMD drivers and restart, I'm such a nub. Thank you @BeGood